# How to download file with presigned url (x-amz-algorithm) using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I have a image url such as

```
https://your-bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/your-item-path.jpg? \
X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256& \
X-Amz-Credential=credential-region-aws4_request& \
X-Amz-Date=20190805T051739Z& \
X-Amz-Expires=300& \
X-Amz-SignedHeaders=headers& \
X-Amz-Signature=url-signature
```

I can open the link in browser. Is there a way to download the file via python.
Thanks

I tried `response = requests.get(url)` but dont know how to download it

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution.

```
response = requests.get(url,stream=True)
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open('test.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        response.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, f)
```

Comment: Can you simplify it to `with open('test.jpg', 'wb') as f: f.write(response.content)`?